# Cannot call non-virtual function of a class template from c# code

Tags: c#, c++, inheritance, c++-cli

In managed c++ project I have class template `BaseClass` which contains virtual method `virtMethod()` and non-virtual instance method `nonVirtMethod()`.

```
template<typename T>
public ref class BaseClass {
public:     
    virtual void virtMethod() {

    }

    void nonVirtMethod() {

    }
};
```

I also have class `DerivedClass` which is inherited from class template `BaseClass`

```
public ref class DerivedClass : public BaseClass<System::String> {
public:
    DerivedClass();
};
```

In c++ project i can call both `virtMethod()` and `nonVirtMethod()`from `DerivedClass` instance, but in c# project, which is referencing the c++ project library, i can call only `virtMethod()`. Can you explain me why it happens, why i cannot call method `nonVirtMethod()` from `DerivedClass` class instance unless it is virtual?

In C++(/clr) project. All is ok:

```
auto obj = gcnew DerivedClass();
obj->nonVirtMethod();
```

In C# project. Error, `DerivedClass` does not contain a defenition for `nonVirtMethod()`:

```
var obj = new DerivedClass();
obj.nonVirtMethod();
```

Comment: I don't see a definition of the `List()` method in the code in the question. Did you mean that to be `nonVirtMethod()` instead?

Comment: @Andy oh yeah, sry, copy pasted from original code, i'll edit now

Comment: Using native C++ templates is a problem, the compiler only generates code for them if they get actually used.  By the C++ code itself, not the C# code.  Use the `generic` keyword to write generic code, it does not have that problem.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/extensions/generic-classes-cpp-cli

Comment: @HansPassant i cannot use `generic` instead of `template` because i'm using the class with non-generic types inside, but you were actually right, compiler just doesn't generate code for `nonVirtMethod()`. Thank you very much for your help, if you write ur comment as answer i'll accept it.